# Function to split a conjoined string of filenames into an an array of filenames

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, slice

Hello this function I created should be able to split each individual file in the string and return an array of different filenames for example "abc.pdf xyz.txt mzm.docx" should return ["abc.pdf","xyz.txt","mzm.docx"]. The output I received from my created function split the string 4 times at some .txt.

```
let txt = '101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a  FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations  and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand  gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely  ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt 201 A6 Sickle Cell.txt 201 A7 Thalassaemia.txt 201 A8 Functions-and-diseases-of-red-and-white-blood-cells.pdf 201 A9 Anatomical planes.pptx 201 B COPD and Asthma(Respiratory Resources).pptx 201 B1 COPD Breathlessness_Manual.pdf 201 B10 Stroke Assessment  Year 2 Kean 2018.pptx 201 B11 GCS Glasgow coma scale article.pdf 201 B11 Stroke_Scale.pdf 201 B12 Neuro chart.pdf 201 B13 assessing dementia.pptx 201 B14 Parkinson’s Disease.pptx 201 B15 NHS Millionaire Quiz Neuro.pptx 201 B16  Surgical Assessment and Care.pptx 201 B17 Mitchell enhanced recovery.pdf 201 B2 COPD 2011 Outcomes strategy.pdf 201 B3 acute asthma management article.pdf 201 B4  asthma still kills full report.pdf 201 B4 Respiratory.pathology.ppt 201 B5 Genetics for Nurses(Genetic Resourses).ppt 201 B6  Atherosclerosis 205(Cardiology Resources).ppt 201 B7 hypertension.ppt 201 B8 CHD.pptx 201 B9 Acquired Brain Injury Assessment(Neurological Resources).pptx 201 BP 19 ain ivpca ARTICLE.pdf 201 C Narrated Principles of Palliative Care.pptx 201 C1  Updated  Narrated Loss Seminar.pptx 201 C10 Obstetric emergencies adult nursing December 2019 moodle.ppt 201 C11 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C12 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C13 doc Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 201 C14 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 2.ppt 201 C15 Manual Handling.ppt 201 C16 Renal System.pptx 201 C17 Excretory Renal and Liver A to E Assessment (1).pptx 201 C2 SUDDEN-CWG-.pdf 201 C3 rapid cancer referral guidelines.pdf 201 C4 Care of the dying adult NG31 guidance.pdf 201 C5 GSF Gold standards Nice 2015 care of the dying.pdf 201 C6 cancer-infection-and-sepsis-fact-sheet.pdf 201 C7 Cancer therapeutic interventions answer SE slides.pptx 201 C8 Help is at Hand guide (1).pdf 201 C9 Adult Safeguarding. Roles and Competencies for Health Care Staff.pdf';
function splitText(){
  let arr = [];
  for (var i = 3; i < txt.length; i++) {
    if(txt.charAt(i) === ' '){
      let threeLastChar = txt.charAt(i-1) + txt.charAt(i-2) + txt.charAt(i-3);
      if(["ppt","ptx","ptm","doc","ocx","txt","pdf"].includes(threeLastChar)){
        arr.push(txt.slice(0,i));
        
      }
    }
  
  }
  return arr; 
}

console.log(splitText());
```

The output:

```
"101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt",
"101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt",
"101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt 201 A6 Sickle Cell.txt",
"101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt 201 A6 Sickle Cell.txt 201 A7 Thalassaemia.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very strange question, but anyway, here is working example:

```js
let txt = "101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a  FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations  and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand  gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely  ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt 201 A6 Sickle Cell.txt 201 A7 Thalassaemia.txt 201 A8 Functions-and-diseases-of-red-and-white-blood-cells.pdf 201 A9 Anatomical planes.pptx 201 B COPD and Asthma(Respiratory Resources).pptx 201 B1 COPD Breathlessness_Manual.pdf 201 B10 Stroke Assessment  Year 2 Kean 2018.pptx 201 B11 GCS Glasgow coma scale article.pdf 201 B11 Stroke_Scale.pdf 201 B12 Neuro chart.pdf 201 B13 assessing dementia.pptx 201 B14 Parkinson’s Disease.pptx 201 B15 NHS Millionaire Quiz Neuro.pptx 201 B16  Surgical Assessment and Care.pptx 201 B17 Mitchell enhanced recovery.pdf 201 B2 COPD 2011 Outcomes strategy.pdf 201 B3 acute asthma management article.pdf 201 B4  asthma still kills full report.pdf 201 B4 Respiratory.pathology.ppt 201 B5 Genetics for Nurses(Genetic Resourses).ppt 201 B6  Atherosclerosis 205(Cardiology Resources).ppt 201 B7 hypertension.ppt 201 B8 CHD.pptx 201 B9 Acquired Brain Injury Assessment(Neurological Resources).pptx 201 BP 19 ain ivpca ARTICLE.pdf 201 C Narrated Principles of Palliative Care.pptx 201 C1  Updated  Narrated Loss Seminar.pptx 201 C10 Obstetric emergencies adult nursing December 2019 moodle.ppt 201 C11 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C12 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C13 doc Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 201 C14 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 2.ppt 201 C15 Manual Handling.ppt 201 C16 Renal System.pptx 201 C17 Excretory Renal and Liver A to E Assessment (1).pptx 201 C2 SUDDEN-CWG-.pdf 201 C3 rapid cancer referral guidelines.pdf 201 C4 Care of the dying adult NG31 guidance.pdf 201 C5 GSF Gold standards Nice 2015 care of the dying.pdf 201 C6 cancer-infection-and-sepsis-fact-sheet.pdf 201 C7 Cancer therapeutic interventions answer SE slides.pptx 201 C8 Help is at Hand guide (1).pdf 201 C9 Adult Safeguarding. Roles and Competencies for Health Care Staff.pdf";

let r1 = (txt + ' ').split(/(.pdf |.txt |.pptx |.docx |.ppt )/);

let r2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < r1.length - 1; i++) {
    let name = r1[i];
  let ext = r1[i + 1];
  i++;
  r2.push(name + ext.trim());
}

console.log(r2)
```

If you need more extensions, add them to this part: `/(.pdf |.txt |.pptx |.docx |.ppt )/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below piece :

```js
let txt = '101 1b communication SOLER to SURETY article.pdf 101 A Foundation of Communication and Proffessionalsm.pptm 101 A1 Reflective models used in Nursing (1).pptx 101 A1a Reflection.pptx 101 B Cultural Awareness (Embracing Diversity).pptx 101 B1 Seminar Cultural Awareness w2.pptx 101 B1a culture and communication article.pdf 101 B1b Cultural Awareness padlet.pdf 101 C Seminar Verbal and Non Verbal Communication w3.pptx 101 C1 Seminar Written communication w3.pptx 101 C1a  FULL Verbal and Non Verbal (2) (2).pptx 101 C1c Communication Challenges that you identified that you may face in practice in the Lead Lecture 08.docx 101 D Active Listening and Empathy presentation.ppt 101 D1 Seminar Active listening Communication Skills.pptx 101 E Communication in specific situations  and Breaking bad news.pptx 101 F Professionalism.pptx 101 G Skills Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 101 G2 manual handling 2.pptx 101 G3 Safe Manual Handling for Bariatric Client.ppt 101 G4 infection control skills.pptx 101 G5 Skill Use of hand  gel.docx 101 G6 5 moments of handwashing.pdf 101 G7 RCN guidance_glovesdermatitis.pdf 101 G8 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 1.pptx 101 G9 Paediatric Choking (2).pptx 102 A Health and wellbeing intro lecture -.pptx 102 A1 Admissions.pptx 102 A2 Itro. to health assessment.pptx 102 B The Purpose of Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B1 Assessment as a concept.pptx 102 B2 Introduction to Risk Assessment in Nursing.pptx 102 B3 Models of Nursing.pptx 102 B4 Nursing Models and the nursing process.ppt 102 B5 First Aid and Aseptic technique.pptx 102 B6 National Early Warning Score NEWS.pptx 102 C Data Collection in Assessment.pptx 102 C1 Introduction to Assessment Tools.pptx 102 C2 NICE acutely  ill patients.pdf 102 C4 NEWS 2 clinical skills.pptx 201 A cells (The Scientific Foundation of Nursing).ppt 201 A1 Cardiovascular assessment.pptx 201 A2 Homeostasis.ppt 201 A3 CVS.ppt 201 A4 Fetal Circulation before birth.txt 201 A5 Fetal Circulation after birth.txt 201 A6 Sickle Cell.txt 201 A7 Thalassaemia.txt 201 A8 Functions-and-diseases-of-red-and-white-blood-cells.pdf 201 A9 Anatomical planes.pptx 201 B COPD and Asthma(Respiratory Resources).pptx 201 B1 COPD Breathlessness_Manual.pdf 201 B10 Stroke Assessment  Year 2 Kean 2018.pptx 201 B11 GCS Glasgow coma scale article.pdf 201 B11 Stroke_Scale.pdf 201 B12 Neuro chart.pdf 201 B13 assessing dementia.pptx 201 B14 Parkinson’s Disease.pptx 201 B15 NHS Millionaire Quiz Neuro.pptx 201 B16  Surgical Assessment and Care.pptx 201 B17 Mitchell enhanced recovery.pdf 201 B2 COPD 2011 Outcomes strategy.pdf 201 B3 acute asthma management article.pdf 201 B4  asthma still kills full report.pdf 201 B4 Respiratory.pathology.ppt 201 B5 Genetics for Nurses(Genetic Resourses).ppt 201 B6  Atherosclerosis 205(Cardiology Resources).ppt 201 B7 hypertension.ppt 201 B8 CHD.pptx 201 B9 Acquired Brain Injury Assessment(Neurological Resources).pptx 201 BP 19 ain ivpca ARTICLE.pdf 201 C Narrated Principles of Palliative Care.pptx 201 C1  Updated  Narrated Loss Seminar.pptx 201 C10 Obstetric emergencies adult nursing December 2019 moodle.ppt 201 C11 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C12 Saving-Mothers--Lives---Early-Obstetric-Warning-Sy.pdf 201 C13 doc Manual Handling Workbook  September 2017.pdf 201 C14 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation yr 2.ppt 201 C15 Manual Handling.ppt 201 C16 Renal System.pptx 201 C17 Excretory Renal and Liver A to E Assessment (1).pptx 201 C2 SUDDEN-CWG-.pdf 201 C3 rapid cancer referral guidelines.pdf 201 C4 Care of the dying adult NG31 guidance.pdf 201 C5 GSF Gold standards Nice 2015 care of the dying.pdf 201 C6 cancer-infection-and-sepsis-fact-sheet.pdf 201 C7 Cancer therapeutic interventions answer SE slides.pptx 201 C8 Help is at Hand guide (1).pdf 201 C9 Adult Safeguarding. Roles and Competencies for Health Care Staff.pdf';


let split=txt.split(/(?<=\.[a-zA-Z]{3,}) /gim);

console.log(split);
```